# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier * has already been declare

Tags: javascript

Hola soy nuevo con esto de la programación e intente hacer que los productos se vallan a el carrito de compras pero al probar me sale error y que el problema es la primera fila diciendo que ya esta declarado

```
    const carro = new carrito();
    const carrito = document.getElementById('carrito');
    const productos = document.getElementById('lista-productos');
    const listaProductos = document.querySelector('#lista-carrito tbody');

    cargarEventos();

    function cargarEventos(){
    productos.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{carrito.comprarProducto(e)});
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

disculpen ya lo solucione al parecer no estaba declarando muy bien ya que no me di cuenta que al principio carrito era con mayuscula la "C" se me olvido que era de esa forma y que al final en:

```
    e)=>{carrito.comprarProducto(e)});
```

no era "carrito" si no que era "carro":

```
    e)=>{carro.comprarProducto(e)});
```

Comment: Ademas, asegurta de siempre usar nombres de Class con MAYUSCULA, ahi estas declarando la clase carrito() con minuscula, y luego llamas a la variable carrito tambien.